# Castel Windsor - store object to XML configuration file

Tags: xml, castle-windsor, store

I would like to know if it is possible this scenario:

1. I configure Windsor IoC from XML file, eg. Settings.xml
2. Then I resolve some object, eg. settings
3. Then I edit props on this object
4. Finally I want store object back to XML file.  Has Windsor some method for this purpose?

Or exist some pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking at [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx). It's orthogonal to IoC container

Comment: So windsor castle IoC doesn’t have any buil-in functionality for this purpose?

Comment: This is not what containers are for